# XSLT 1.0: Efficiently Compare Two Nodesets for a Match

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a sequence of Color elements like this:

```
<Colors>
    <Color Name ="AliceBlue"    Hex="#F0F8FF"/>
    <Color Name ="AntiqueWhite" Hex="#FAEBD7"/>
    <!-- more values... -->
</Colors>
```

And a sequence of words:

```
<Words>
    <Element>1px</Element>
    <Element>Blue</Element>
    <Element>Solid</Element>
</Words>
```

What is an efficient way to find where a `Colors/Color/@name` attribute exactly matches a node in `Words/Element/text()`, and retrieve that @name?

Comment: Are these two node-sets in the same document? If yes, use a [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key). If not, use a key anyway - but it will be a little more complicated to set up.  -- P.S. An example with an actual match would be more useful, as would be the expected output. -- P.P.S. There is no "intersection" here; no node is common to both sets.

Comment: Edited the title accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @michael.hor257k suggested, you could use keys for this; assuming this sample document:

```
<root>
  <Colors>
    <Color Name ="AliceBlue"    Hex="#F0F8FF"/>
    <Color Name ="AntiqueWhite" Hex="#FAEBD7"/>
    <Color Name="AnotherColor" Hex="123" />
    <!-- more values... -->
  </Colors>
  <Words>
    <Element>1px</Element>
    <Element>Blue</Element>
    <Element>AntiqueWhite</Element>
    <Element>AliceBlue</Element>
  </Words>
</root>
```

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="colors" match="/root/Colors/Color" use="@Name" />
    <xsl:template match="/root/Words/Element[key('colors', .)]">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:transform>
```

Would output the names of colors that match in both the `Element` and `Color` nodes.  Here's the [XSLTransform](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaGn).